# Convert Image to SVG using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg

I want convert Image file (PNG,JPG) to SVG using C#. But I don't want to have image/base64 string in my svg tag.

Comment: So are you asking how to trace it, or…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG means [Scalable Vector Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), which is not an image in the way a .PNG or .JPG is. Rather than storing an array of pixels, it stores a list of mathematical shapes and designs. The intent of an SVG is to create an 'image' that retains quality regardless of how far you zoom in or out.

There is no benefit to converting .PNG to .SVG - in fact, it loses quite a bit of quality because you can't literally "convert" it, you can only trace it (IE, draw a new SVG that looks like the PNG.)

In summary: I think you're asking the wrong thing here, or you simply don't understand what you're asking. Please clarify if you can.

Comment: I want also to convert it from a png to svg.
Since it's easyer to read a svg and cordinate the lines for a printer I'm making. Hard to find a solution..

Answer (score -1):

I've used the website below and got great results converting logos and what-have-you to vector formats. I have no connection to them:

http://vectormagic.com/home

Comment: whether it is possible to use this program using command line?